# Pure Virtual Destructor with Default Keyword

Tags: c++, c++11, virtual-functions

Is it possible to declare a destructor as pure virtual and use the default keyword? For example, I can't seem to make code like this work:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
  // Is there a way to combine pure virtual and default?
  virtual ~ MyClass() = 0,default;
};
```

One can of course later do:

```
MyClass::~ MyClass() = default;
```

Also, if the destructor is not pure virtual, the default keyword does work when it follows the declaration.

Comment: Right, thanks. The standard indeed says 
> a function declaration cannot provide both a pure-specifier and a definition

Comment: @T.C. Answers go down there, bub.  ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓

Comment: default a virtual destuctor ... What [for](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31672207/2567683) ? It's virtual so defaulting it won't make it trivial and nothing changes for your class from defining it as `{ }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No.**

You will have to write a separate definition and `default` it there, as you've shown.

The presence of a *pure-specifier* precludes the presence of a definition at the same location, even when that definition is just a `= default`.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible.

By declaring the member function with the `= default` specifier, you are providing a function definition.

From the working draft of the C++14 standard (N3936):

> § 10.4 Note: A function declaration cannot provide both a pure-specifier and a definition

https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/raw/b7b8ed08ba4c111ad03e13e8524a1b746cb74ec6/papers/N3936.pdf

Comment: N3797 is by far not the "latest publicly available draft"

Comment: @T.C. I used the "latest publicly available draft" link from this URL: http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/ . Please provide a URL to a more recent draft if you have one.

Comment: Notes are not normative but that note is also present in `N4140`

Answer (score -4):

This question is sort of a non-starter, since [you can only have one destructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21934810/why-a-class-has-only-one-destructor) anyway. Why would you need to add a `default` specifier?

Comment: Wouldn't that apply to anything you can use `default` on?

Comment: You forgot that a pure virtual function may have a definition.